# Controling Views with router, backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I've a problem with my backbone.js application, i want to Control which subviev is rendered with a backbone router, but i keep having problems with the namespaces. I get a "Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined" error, and all other solutions i tried where without success. There may be a better solution to control view with a router, but i tried other solution for 3 hours without success.
I hope you can help me.

Here is my code:

```
(function($){    


var App = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'),

    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.mainApp = new LoginApp();
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
        $(this.el).append(this.mainApp.render().$el);
    },
    setmainApp: function(mApp) {
        this.mainApp = mApp;
    }
});

var LoginApp =Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).append("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
        return this;    
    }
});

var RegisterApp =Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).append("<h1>Hello World2</h1>");
        return this;    
    }
});


//Router
var AppRouter =Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes : {
        "login" : "login",
        "register": "register",
        '*path':  'defaultRoute'
    },
    login: function() {
        //Problem
        app.setmainApp(new LoginApp);
        app.render();
    },
    register: function() {
        app.setmainApp(new RegisterApp);
        app.render();
    },
    defaultRoute: function() {
        app.setmainApp(new LoginApp);
        app.render();
    }
});
var appRouter = new AppRouter;
Backbone.history.start();
app = new App();

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the order:

```
var appRouter = new AppRouter;
app = new App();
Backbone.history.start();
```